# Legendre Symbol: show that $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=\left(\frac p3\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

I am asked to solve the following question

> Let $p$ be a prime, $p>3$. By considering the cases $p ≡1\bmod4$ and $p≡-1\bmod4$ separately, show that $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=\left(\frac p3\right)$.

So if $p ≡ 1\bmod4$, $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=\left(\frac p{-3}\right)$ and if $p ≡ -1\bmod4$, $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=-\left(\frac p{-3}\right)$.

And then I get stuck on how to process on; is there anything I can do to deal with the minus sign of $3$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if $p\not\equiv3\pmod{4}$.